# regex for preg_replace: separate path and filename

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, filenames, filepath

In PHP I try to achieve to change a string:

```
<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-18" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/300x149-jquerymobile.jpg" alt="jquerymobile" width="300" height="149">
```

to this:

```
<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-18" src="" data-path="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/" data-img="300x149-jquerymobile.jpg" alt="jquerymobile" width="300" height="149">
```

I want wanna use

```
preg_replace('/src="(what-is-a-path-regex)(.*)"/', 'src="" data-path="$1" data-img="$2"', '<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-18" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/300x149-jquerymobile.jpg" alt="jquerymobile" width="300" height="149">')
```

What regex is to replace "wat-is-a-path-regex"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: `(https?:\/\/.+\/)(.+)`. An example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/oC0kE6/1).

That being said, you *should* see if it is possible to combine this approach with a DOM parse so that you can extract the property you need first.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below,

```
preg_replace('~src="(.*?\/)([^/"]*)"~', 'src="" data-path="\1" data-img="\2"', '<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-18" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/300x149-jquerymobile.jpg" alt="jquerymobile" width="300" height="149">');
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yP1kI0/3)

`[^/"]*` negated character class which matches any character but not of `"` or `/` , zero or more times.